# Office 365 Powershell Logs Got Very Large

Tags: powershell, logging, office365

I have many scheduled jobs running on a server in our environment, but this morning a monitoring team contacted me about a service account profile eating up all the disk space. I dug around and found logs in C:\Users\service_account\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office365\Powershell directory, but 3 of them on different dates were over 10 GB in size.

I narrowed it down to one script we have the checks the AD dir sync every hour to make sure it doesn't take longer than an hour, but I'm not sure what the best practice is for this? Also, most logs in this location are only 4 kb in size and indicate typical tracking like, connection times, cmdlets initializing, etc.

I'm not sure how to open such a huge file to see what may be the problem. Has anyone else run into this kind of thing? I can't find much on line. Also, I do run Remove-pssession * to close my sessions. Thx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

Read your file from disk one line or groups of lines at a time, work with each line, and then  write each line back out to disk., if needed. 
Instead of caching the entire file in RAM by using plain Get-Content, you’re reading it off disk a bit at a time. The below represents a very simplistic example of how to do this.

```
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "test.txt"
while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
  # $line has your line
}
$file.close()
```

Or using ...

```
Get-Content -Readcount 100
```

... to process chunks of lines at a time, the above will give you arrays of 100 lines each.

There are recent posts on this forum regarding folks working with large files and PoSH and having to resort to using th e System.IO.StreamReader / System.IO.StreamWriter .Net aproach to handle the use case.

For example:
[Unable to Find and Replace a string in 2GB XML file using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142743/unable-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-2gb-xml-file-using-powershell)

But there are lots more on this forum, just search for them using [powershell] large file

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. I'm assuming this is the storage location for Office365PowerShell events? Not sure I need these and may opt to delete them once a month?